# При изменении изображения в ImageView перестает работать анимация

Tags: java, android, imageview, objectanimator

Вот код

```
public void ChangeImage(View view) {
    ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
    if (change_image == false) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ss);
        change_image = true;
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.s);
        change_image = false;
    }
    image.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю, что проблема не в изменении изображения.

Метод [`animate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#animate()) всегда ["возвращает один и тот же"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40308874) объект [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator), у которого метод [`alpha()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#alpha(float)) вызовет анимацию свойства `alpha` до указанного значения, причём **уже запущенная анимация свойства  будет отменена**.

Таким образом, Вам следует использовать [Animator.AnimatorListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener) так, как показано [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498882): необходимо определить, полностью ли прозрачно изображение, и только потом изменять его и назначать новую анимацию.

---

Непроверенный код:

```
ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = image.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        if (change_image == false) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ss);
            change_image = true;
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.s);
            change_image = false;
        }
        image.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
    }
});
```

Comment: А почему она будет отменена?

Comment: И можете объяснить, зачем мы Lisener ставим?

Comment: @Houl она будет отменена, потому что таково её поведение, такой её сделали... `AnimatorListener` необходим для того, чтобы точно определить, когда первая анимация была завершена, чтобы начать вторую